# iTunes charges when it's advertised as free

Tags: ios-appstore

Why does it advertise free for 3D tour of ancient Jewish temple then when I try to install the app it asks for credit card details

Answer (score 0):

Verifying your credit card does not mean you are being charged.

If there is a change in your billing info, you have to verify it once on each device that uses that AppleID in order to continue downloading from iTunes. This does not mean you are being charged.